# Java jax-ws catalog files: difference between PUBLIC and SYSTEM entries

Tags: java, jax-ws, xjc, wsimport

Can somebody explain the difference between SYSTEM and PUBLIC entries in the following TR9401 catalog format (which I use with Java **jax-ws** tools like `xjc`, `wsimport` etc.) The same concepts (SYSTEM and PUBLIC) appear in the other XML catalog formats as well.

In other words, I see the catalog file as a map: namespace (key) to location (value). What does it mean for a key-value pair in that map to be "SYSTEM" as opposed to "PUBLIC" ?

```
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd" "xml.xsd"
SYSTEM "http://www.ivoa.net/xml/STC/STCregion/v1.10" "STCregion-v1.10.xsd"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XMLSCHEMA 200102//EN" "XMLSchema.dtd"
PUBLIC "http://www.ivoa.net/xml/STC/STCcoords/v1.10" "STCcoords-v1.10-mod.xsd"
```

I've experimented a bit and have found that I can change certain entries from PUBLIC to SYSTEM and it still works, while the same change on other lines breaks the build.

Comment: You are aware of the difference between DTD and XSD?

Comment: @TRA, yes. I tampered with the XSD schemas regarding SYSTEM/PUBLIC, didn't touch the XMLSchema.dtd.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think it comes from [SGML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language)/[DTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition) where every document-type can have a [PUBLIC-ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_Public_Identifier) and a [SYSTEM-ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_identifier). The former is just a sequence of characters (e.g. `-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN`), the latter is a filename or an [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL).

In XML, *xmlns* is more or less the public-id while *schemaLocation* can be regarded as system-id.

An example I've just found on my computer: there is a `/usr/share/xml/schema/xml-core/tr9401.dtd` file that has a public-id `-//GlobalTransCorp//DTD XML Catalogs V1.0-Based Extension V1.0//EN` and a system-id `http://globaltranscorp.org/oasis/catalog/xml/tr9401.dtd`.

Now the `catalog.xml` file contains these lines:

```
<public publicId="-//GlobalTransCorp//DTD XML Catalogs V1.0-Based Extension V1.0//EN" uri="tr9401.dtd"/>
<system systemId="http://globaltranscorp.org/oasis/catalog/xml/tr9401.dtd" uri="tr9401.dtd"/>
```

The first resolves the public-id into an actual local file; the second resolves the system-id into an actual local file.